# Unhandled errors are not coming to user designated for 2GMP

Tags: managed-package, notification, 2gp, second-generation-packaging, unhandled-exception

Apex documentation has contradicting information about Second Generation(2GP) Package Apex Unhandled Exception support.

[This page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_known_limitations.htm) states that Apex exception errors don’t trigger email notifications.

While [this page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_package.htm) states that it is possible to set a user to receive unhandled apex exception email notification

```
-o | --errornotificationusername ERRORNOTIFICATIONUSERNAME
Optional
An active Dev Hub org user designated to receive email notifications for unhandled Apex exceptions, and install, upgrade, or uninstall failures associated with your package.
Type: string
```

I have confirmed that the package I created, was created with setting `errornotificationusername` to the correct values. Also I did receive some email notifications about installation errors.

I can't understand if the Second Generation(2GP) Package support Apex Unhandled Exception email notifications or not. Since I was able to receive email notifications about package install errors, despite the documentation specifies these are not supported either. If this is not supported, what is the purpose of setting `errornotificationusername` attribute?

I have seen some [other issues related to Apex unhandled email exceptions not coming at all or classic packaging or unpackaged code](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V0000003vrOQAQ). Am I affected by the same issue?

Comment: I have reached out to our team internally and will share more inputs as I have. Thank you

Comment: Thanks @Swetha, please let me know when you have any information on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our Salesforce team has identified this reported scenario as a documentation bug. The relevant change which is removing the point `Apex exception errors don’t trigger email notifications` from the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_known_limitations.htm)  has been done and is expected to reflect by 26/05(Safe Harbor).

Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Ok, so Apex exception errors should trigger email notifications, correct? Then why didn't I receive those expected unhandled error email notifications?

Comment: That's correct. To be able to understand which expected email notifications weren't sent, we need more details on the scenario. I'd recommend logging a support case for further investigation.

Comment: Is premier support required for opening case like this? If so, I have to check with my client if they have it enabled

Comment: I believe this needs Premier support @Patlatus