# Do 2GP Managed Packages send email notifications on unhandled Apex errors?

Tags: managed-package, error-messages, isv, bug, 2gp

Other than the [official documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_package.htm#cli_reference_force_package_create) and [related SFSE questions](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/342966) indicate the Error reporting of Second Generation Managed Packages (2GP) seems to behave differently that with 1GP.

I want to make this tool work with 2GP Managed Packages: https://github.com/rsoesemann/lma-app-cockpit but couldn't get a 2GP Managed Package that was created using the `errornotificationusername` parameter to send notification emails on Unhandled Apex Errors.

**Is this supposed to work or did I discover a bug?**

Comment: Is there a question in here somewhere, or just info sharing? Did you raise a support case with Salesforce?

Comment: You are right. Added a question if this is a bug or supposed to work. I will also create a support case and put the Id here later.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Yes, unhandled exception emails do work with 2GP.

I confirmed this by creating a managed 2GP with a Visualforce Controller that tries to divide by zero if a certain custom metadata record is set to `true`.

**Here's how I set up my test:**

1. Created managed 2GP using `force:package:create`.
2. Used `force:package:update` with the `--ERRORNOTIFICATIONUSERNAME` flag and provided the username of a user from the DevHub that I used to create the 2GP.
3. Created and promoted a package version with my test code
4. Installed the package version in an ACTIVE (i.e. production) Enterprise Edition org.
5. Performed an action that triggered the unhandled exception.

#### Figure 1: Unhandled Exception in the Subcriber Org

[image: Unhandled Apex exception in the subscriber org.]

#### Figure 2: Unhandled Exception Email Received ~5 Minutes Later

[image]

#### Possible Reasons for Missing Unhandled Exception Emails

This [Known Issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V0000003vrOQAQ) highlights the fact that Apex exception emails are rate-limited to a few hundred emails **per hour** for a given instance.  This is also referenced in the Apex Developer Guide on the [Exceptions in Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_exception_definition.htm) page.

> Apex exception emails are limited to 10 emails per hour, per application server. Because this limit isn’t on a per-org basis, email delivery to a particular org can be unreliable.

Depending on the type of unhandled exception and the frequency of that exception type being thrown on a given instance, you might intermittently miss out on getting Apex exception emails.

#### Best Practices for Surfacing Apex Exceptions in Managed Packages

The recommended course of action for ISV partners is to use [AppExchange App Analytics](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/app_analytics_intro.htm) to surface exceptions from within managed packages.  To do this, filter your [package usage logs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/app_analytics_custom_object_logs.htm) by the `log_record_type` value of `ApexUnexpectedException`.

To learn more about AppExchange App Analytics, check out the [AppExchange Partner Intelligence Basics](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/appexchange-partner-intelligence-basics) module on Trailhead.

Comment: You rock Vivek!

Comment: Thanks, @RobertSösemann! Sorry it took so long for me to get back to you on this.

Answer (score 0):

Apex Error Email for Unlocked Packages were introduced in Winter 21

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_sfdx_packaging_set_error_notification.htm&type=5&release=228

Hence they should be supported. The CLI docs and release notes mention that an active devhub user must be designated but don't mention if all devhub orgs support these emails.

Comment: Exactelly that is the documentation I also mention in my question. Should work for Unlocked and Managed 2GP.